# What's with "jusqu'à ce que"?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, conjonctions

This one always confused me a bit. I'm looking for a better understanding of when to use it versus when to only use *jusqu'à* versus when to use *jusque*, if that's even a word by itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Avec une subordonnée, on utilisera *jusqu'à ce que*

> Je lirai jusqu'à ce que je tombe de sommeil
>
> *I'll read until I fall asleep*

Avec un nom ou un verbe à l'infinitif, on utilisera simplement *jusqu'à*

> J'ai regardé ce film jusqu'à la fin / J'ai lu jusqu'à tomber de sommeil
>
> *I watched the movie until the end* / *I read until falling asleep*

Enfin, avec un complément ou un adverbe par exemple, on utilisera *jusque*, ou *jusqu'* si le mot suivant commence par une voyelle ou un "h" muet.

> Ils ont mis des caméras jusque dans les toilettes / J'irai jusque là / Ça pue jusqu'ici
>
> *They put cameras even in the lavatories* / *I'll go up to that point* / *It stinks up to here*

Comment: Il y a aussi `jusqu'ici` ou `jusque là`.

Comment: @M42 : j'ai rajouté ces deux exemples, merci!

Comment: LOL "I slept until falling asleep" that's almost poetic

Comment: Also, why do you use the future tense in this answer?...I would have expected conditional. Am I completely wrong, or would that also be okay? *"On utiliserait..."* I understand the use of the *futur*, I'm just wondering whether you *could* use conditional.

Comment: Both future and conditionnal would be correct. Indicative present would be correct too. I chose the future though for its old-school, grammar teacher style it evokes (to me at least :) )

Comment: @Aerovistae Le futur ici, indique un choix possible : "Pour répondre à cette situation on *utilisera* soit cette solution, soit celle-ci."

Comment: @cl-r I'm sorry, I read that four times but my French is just not good enough yet to understand the "soit cette solution, soit celle-ci." / Désolé, je les ai lu quatre fois mais mon français ne suffit pas pour comprendre les mots *soit cette solution, soit celle-ci.*

Comment: @Aerovistae Mirrored situation, my english is so poor. Something like : "In this case you will use this response/solution or this other one." **soit** est un *adverbe* qui indique une alternative.

Comment: @Aerovistae "soit ... soit ..." can be translated into "either ... or ..." : *You can use either this solution, or that one*

Comment: Ah, merci à les deux. (Ça se marche?)

Comment: @Aerovistae *Merci à vous deux (Ça marche? / C'est correct?)*.