# « être certain que » / « être certain de ce que »

Tags: grammaire, usage, prépositions, subordonnées

#### The kernel of the question

I recently said:

> Je ne suis pas tout à fait certain **de ce que** ces phrases soient naturelles.

Later, @Laure helpfully suggested this simplification:

> Je ne suis pas tout à fait certain **que** ces phrases soient naturelles.

Sure enough, [this Ngram](http://ow.ly/PEoB30cGUeh) shows *certain de ce que* absolutely flatlining compared to *certain que*. But [This one](http://ow.ly/lPLO30cGJvQ) shows that *content de ce que* is used, albeit  less commonly than *content que*. I'm surprised to see that they're so different! What should I gather from this correction?

1. Does "*être [adj.] que*" alternate with "*être [adj.] de ce que*" stylistically, perhaps along the lines of classic vs. modern?
2. Is *être [adj.] de ce que*" regarded as incorrect?
3. Does it entirely depend on the adjective?

Which of the above explanations is correct (or is another one)? What else should I know about *de ce que* and *à ce que* in contexts like these?

---

#### Background / what I've learned so far

After having searched a little to see whether my question has already been answered, the closest I found was [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24063/why-do-we-need-ce-in-surtout-ne-t-attends-pas-%C3%A0-ce-que-je-puisse-te-parler), which I'll build on in the belief that the *à ce que*, *de ce que* discussed there works like the one above.

To summarize what I've gathered: This particular construction *ce que* preceded by a preposition introduces a verbal clause, generally in the subjunctive. It completes certain expressions and can also explain the alternative forms of expressions like ["de manière (à ce) que"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/de-mani%C3%A8re-que-vs-de-mani%C3%A8re-%C3%A0-ce-que) and ["rapport à ce que"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20151/par-rapport-que-rapport-%C3%A0-ce-que-%C3%A0-cause-que-causalit%C3%A9-objective-subjectiv). (However, it's unrelated to [*ce que*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1678/when-do-we-use-ce-que-instead-of-que) "COD + *which*".)

This *ce que* is mandatory in [at least one construction](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/whats-with-jusqu%C3%A0-ce-que) that alternates with a nominal or infinitive complement:

> → Jusqu'à ce que l'année soit / sera terminée.
>   
> → Jusqu'à la fin de l'année.
>   
> → Rire jusqu'à en mourir n'est pas une blague.

At some point during my acquisition of French, based on the first of the above examples, I apparently generalized the rule along these lines:

> Je suis content **de** ton succès.
>   
> Je suis content **de ce que** tu aies *(as ?)* eu du succès.
>
> J'ai peur **des** monstres.
>   
> J'ai peur **de ce que** les monstres viennent.
>
> Ils s'attendent **au** jour de son retour.
>   
> Ils s'attendent **à ce qu**'il revienne.

This brings me about up to where @Catomic was in the question I first cited.

Now, Catomic had found a sentence like one of the above and was wondering why it wasn't:

> Ils s'attendent **qu**'il revienne.

In Laure's answer to Catomic, I learn:

> There's absolutely no difference in meaning between [*s'attendre **à ce que***] and [*s'attendre **que*** ...] the difference lies in what is considered a classical use [*que*] and Gide's modern use [*à ce que*]. In the [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/attendre) (III 3) we can read that both *s'attendre que* and *s'attendre à ce que* are correct but that purists advocate the former and the latter is more usual.

I also learn there that if there *is* a difference in usage, it's that *à ce que* variant can use *l'indicatif du futur simple*, as I did with *sera* above — at least according to Grévisse (Laure at least thinks that sounds odd).

Now @jlliagre, in his answer, draws a distinction between the behaviour of different verbs, e.g. *se préparer* and *se souhaiter* :

> Je me prépare à ce qu'il y ait la guerre. **Correct**
>   
>  Je me prépare qu'il y ait la guerre. **Incorrect**
>
> Je me souhaite à ce qu'il y ait une bonne guerre. **Incorrect**
>   
>  Je me souhaite qu'il y ait une bonne guerre. **Correct**

And his mention of pronominal and reciprocal verbs suggests that the patterns apply differently to different classes of verb.

So I can't necessarily generalize Laure's notes on *s'attendre* as classic vs. modern usage because I may run into simply incorrect uses depending on the verb.

---

That brings us up to my current question. I know that *être [adj.] de* is a different kind of phrase from *[verbe] à*, but I was hoping that the analogy would work on the common ground of "*ce que* + [groupe verbal]".

It would certainly be interesting if *être certain que* was the modern use and *être certain de ce que* was classic/outdated, given that the reverse was the case with *s'attendre que* vs. *s'attendre à ce que*.

Am I on the right track? I guess what I'm asking is, in practical terms, what *can* I use, and what *should* I use, in what contexts, when constructing this kind of sentence?

Comment: Luke, what is the question? I can't follow it. I can say this: Je m'attends à ce qu'il dise la verité. How can that ever be: s'attendre que??

Comment: @Lambie I renamed the question and reorganized it to put the heart of it at the top. It's about *être certain de ce que* vs. *être certain que* and expressions like that. Let me know if it's still too convoluted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also have frowned upon this sentence:

> *Je ne suis pas tout à fait certain de ce que ces phrases soient naturelles.*

Splitting and inverting the sentence order might help understanding what is wrong here.

I wouldn't have written:

> **Ce que ces phrases soient naturelles, je n'en suis pas tout à fait certain.*

because **Ce que ces phrases soient naturelles* is agrammatical (literally: *What these sentences be natural).

What works is, keeping *ce que* :

> *Ce que ces phrases veulent dire, je n'en suis pas tout à fait certain.*

→ What these sentences mean, I'm not absolutely certain about it.

or maintaining the original meaning:

> *Du caractère naturel de ces phrases, je ne suis pas tout à fait certain.*

→ The naturalness of these sentences, I'm not absolutely certain about it.

> *Que ces phrases soient naturelles, je n'en suis pas tout à fait certain .*

→ That these sentences are natural, I'm not absolutely certain about it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure about that first test. *Ce que tu aies eu du succès, j'en suis content. Ce qu'elles arrivent, je m'y attend. Ce qu'ils soient croquants, faites-les cuir jusqu'à.* Each of these sounds either suspicious or downright awful to my ears, but untangling them to their normal orders yields okay sentences. (As for *ce que* the direct object and the alternative ways to phrase this particular sentence, I'm fairly comfortable with those usages and am wondering more technically about the limitations of this particular *ce que* before verb phrases.)

Comment: I do not agree with "untangling them to their normal order yields okay sentences". *Que tu aies du succès* is okay but whatever the order, *ce que tu aies du succès* is ungrammatical.

Comment: Good to know — so that one can be cleared up (I assumed one could be *content de ce que* given the Ngram results, but it occurs to me that that could be the direct object *ce que* as in *content de ce que tu as dit*). In any case, the other two can certainly be untangled to normal sentences (*je m'attends à ce qu'elles arrivent*, *faites-les cuir jusqu'à ce qu'ils soient croquants*), by which I understand that the awkwardness of the rearrangement doesn't guarantee awkwardness of the original sentence.