# L'expression « avoir besoin que » est-elle standard ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, régionalismes, canada

Parmi mes collègues en formation à l'enseignement il y en a plusieurs qui disent « avoir besoin que » (suivi par le subjonctif) comme dans cet exemple :

> J'ai besoin que tu fasses le travail avant jeudi.

Pour moi c'est un peu bizarre, même si ça semble être une construction parfois difficile à éviter !

Or ces collègues sont sortis de tous les milieux, que ce soit d'une communauté franco-ontarienne, de l'immersion française, ou du français cadre (programme très faible qui représente le minimum du contact avec le français possible pendant la scolarisation ontarienne). Je trouve donc difficile de déterminer si les expressions qu'ils emploient sont courantes ou non.

S'agit-il d'un régionalisme ou d'une faute ?

Comment: On retrouve la même structure avec *avoir envie* et *avoir peur* (J'ai **envie que** tu fasses..., J'ai **peur que** tu fasses...)

Comment: @jlliagre Bien vu !

Comment: On peut aussi noter que ça ne marche pas s'il s'agit de la même personne: **J'ai besoin que je fasse le travail avant jeudi* ou **Tu as besoin que tu fasses le travail...* etc.

Comment: Je vois que vous avez fait une correction et je peux conclure que vous ne croyez pas trop non plus en la légitimité de cette tournure ; toutefois je dois vous faire remarquer qu'il me semble que votre correction n'est pas tout à fait complète ; je crois qu'il soit nécessaire d'écrire « il y **en** a plusieurs qui » ou bien « il y a plusieurs **d'entre eux** qui ». (« Il y a plusieurs qui » semble très rare tout le temps, voir ngram.)

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+y+a+plusieurs+qui%2Cy+en+a+plusieurs+qui&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20y%20a%20plusieurs%20qui%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cy%20en%20a%20plusieurs%20qui%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @LPH Vous avez tout à fait raison. Cela accorde avec mes intuitions lorsque j'y réfléchis au lieu de faire une révision expédiente. :p Merci !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La structure est assez habituelle, et est aussi enregistrée au [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/besoin) :

> Avoir besoin que + verbe au subjonctif

Un corpus de recherche intéressant pour ce genre de tournure est le site de [Gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&query=%28gallica%20adj%20%22j%27ai%20besoin%20que%22%29&lang=en&suggest=0), de la Bibliothèque nationale de France, où l’on peut aussi trouver de nombreuses utilisations dans la littérature.

En voici quelques exemples :

> - Mais **j'ai besoin que tu sois** convaincu que je n'ai pas négligé tes intérêts.
>   <sub>—Choix de lettres d'Eugène Burnouf, 1825-1852</sub>
> - Est-ce que **j'ai besoin que vous vous jetiez** à l'eau si j'y tombe ?
>   <sub>—Correspondance de Gustave Flaubert</sub>
> - J'en suis ravie : **j'ai besoin que vous soyez** monstrueusement en belle humeur tout à l'heure.
>   <sub>—Londres au dix-neuvième siècle, ou l'École du scandale, comédie en 5 actes, en prose, librement traduite et en partie imitée de Sheridan</sub>

Les exemples sont assez rares avant le XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle, mais beaucoup plus fréquents depuis.

---

#### Notes en marge

Il est à remarquer que le mode indicatif avec *« avoir besoin que »* ne fonctionne pas et est immédiatement perçu comme incorrect par les locuteurs natifs.

L’exemple suivant n’est pas un contre-exemple : l’indicatif y est introduit pour définir le sujet, non l’action dont on a besoin de lui (ici *pardonner*) :

> La rapidité avec laquelle j’ai dû composer ce mémoire, m’a à peine permis d’ébaucher mes premières idées. Je n’ai pu leur donner que des liaisons imparfaites : je n’ai pu les vêtir à mon gré. **J’ai besoin que** ceux qui me liront, **pardonnent**, en faveur du bien qu’elles pourront produire, le désordre dans lequel j’ai été forcé de les émettre.
> <sub>—Les grands et les fripons au pilori, ou Guillaume Deynes sur la sellette, Guillaume DEYNES, 1794</sub>

On pourrait à la rigueur, en certains cas particuliers, évoquer un infinitif, mais le subjonctif demeure :

- J’**ai besoin**, pour mener ces travaux à bien, **que détourner** le trafic automobile nous **soit** permis.

Quant à la forme *« n’avoir besoin que de »*, elle accepte l’infinitif, tout en ne le requérant pas, mais le subjonctif sera à éviter :

- Je n’ai besoin que de **préciser** un ou deux détails supplémentaire et je vous laisse aller.
- Je n’ai besoin que d’un bol de soupe et d’un peu de chaleur, je repars sitôt réchauffé.

Comment: Bonne réponse où tu n'as pas négligé mes intérêts. Je suis convaincu ! :p

Comment: Tout autre mode que le subjonctif sera immédiatement identifié comme incorrect : *j'ai besoin que tu `feras` le travail avant jeudi*, *j'ai besoin que tu `fais` le travail* ou *j'ai besoin que tu `ferais` le travail* sont plus qu'improbables.

Comment: Stéphane edited my question to be about the subjunctive, and your addition is helpful, but it was indeed about the acceptability of the expression and not the mode that I was asking. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, je n'avais pas vu qu'il s'agissait d'une édition, je comprends maintenant ! Cette question me rendait perplexe...

Comment: vous dites "assez habituelle, et est aussi enregistrée au TLFi", mais ça ne répond pas à la question : est-ce une faute ? que dit l'Académie ?

Answer (score 2):

La surprise (le *un peu bizarre*) relativement à cette construction est légitime car elle est double :

D'une part :
Dans la plupart des langues germaniques, *avoir besoin* sera rendu par un verbe dit *transitif direct*.
*I need* + COD pour l'anglais, *Ich brauche* + COD pour l'allemand.

D'autre part une question hypothétique ayant une telle réponse serait de la forme :
***De quoi*** ai-je besoin ? voire *J'ai besoin **de quoi ?*** Et non *J'ai besoin quoi* qui serait fautif tant... notre façon de dire n'est pas transitive directe.

La préposition *de* est à ce point nécessaire qu'on la retrouvera usuellement dans les réponses au questions commençant par *de quoi* :
- *De quoi te mêles-tu ? → **De** ce qui me regarde!*
- *De quoi es-tu fait ? → **Du** bois dont on fait les flutes! - De quoi vis-tu ? → **D**'amour et **D**'eau fraiche!*

D'où une tendance tout à fait naturelle (même chez le natif) à calquer ces constructions et à écrire : *J'ai besoin **de**...* quelle que soit la suite de la phrase.

La suite de la phrase, ici, est, comme dans mes deux premiers exemples ci-dessus une subordonnée relative. → antécédent et pronom relatif.

*J'ai besoin **du** tournevis **que** tu tiens entre tes mains, J'ai besoin **de ce que** tu as dans les mains, j'ai besoin du produit que tu fabriques, **j'ai besoin de ce que tu fais.*** (ici, maintenant, factuellement, : indicatif)

Ainsi pourrait-on sans problème pour la grammaire normative dire avec JJ Rousseau :
*"Ignorez-vous qu’une multitude de vos frères périt, ou souffre du besoin de ce que vous avez de trop"*

Ajoutons-y un soupçon de souhait, d'hypothèse heureuse, de politesse... → passage au subj de la subordonnée et on obtient un rien de plus grammaticalement correct :

*J'ai besoin **de ce que** tu fasses ton travail pour demain.*

Je soupçonne que c'est l'absence de ce *de ce* qui te fais sembler le machin... bizarre.
Cette surprise est donc très légitime mais... la construction que tu reportes ici a néanmoins... de *bonnes raisons* d'être ainsi. Je peux développer le cas échéant.

---

**PART II La bonne raison (suite à commentaire de l'OP) :**

Héhé... SAUF... sauf que ici le problème devient, encore une fois, cette @##@&&@@ de @@# absurdité de dictat de transitivité reposant sur le seul critère syntaxique. Quand la sémantique s'en mêle... c'est : le boxif, voyons bien plutôt :

Dans les exemples que j'ai pris (à dessein) on remarque quoi :

J'ai besoin de ce que tu tiens dans tes mains.

- Tu tiens CODx.
- J'ai besoin de **ce même** CODx. (en passant par toi pour le définir)

Nous avons là un cas typique de transitivité indirecte. (J'ai besoin d'un truc qui passe par toi) La non transitivité directe d'avoir besoin n'est pas un problème pour la construction → ***de ce que!***

Dans l'exemple qui nous préoccupe ici, ce n'est pas de ton travail dont j'ai besoin, c'est que tu le fasses, c'est de son accomplissement par toi.
La transitivité (sémantique) est ici très directe et, forcément va très mal s'accommoder de la non transitivité directe syntaxique de l'entame.

Comment m'y prendrais-je avec une entame syntaxiquement TD ? :

*Je présume que tu fais ton travail pour demain* Pas de *de ce* évidemment.

On fait quoi alors... bhein... on va faire une entorse... et faire comme si *J'ai besoin* était... une tournure transitive directe... On calque donc mon dernier exemple et... roule ma poule :

- J'ai besoin que tu... *blahblah*.

Exit le *de ce*.
Nous ne sommes donc pas ici en présence d'une ellipse de *de ce*. Juste en présence d'un fait de langue exemplatif de ce que la transitivité sémantique de la locution verbale (transitivité reconnue en anglais et en allemand) va prendre le dessus sur sa non-transitivité syntaxique. J'ai besoin sera, dans cette phrase, employé... transitivement!

Comme quoi... la transitivité des verbes... enfin! vous savez ce que j'en pense.

<sub>NDaCOSwt : Note bien que... ça fait quand même un poil trafiqué comme bricolage... tant... je me vois mal te poser la question : "*Tu as besoin quoi ?*" ;-) ce qui me fais te suivre dans le fait de trouver tout cela bien... *bizarre*.</sub>

Comment: Une hypothèse intéressante ! En effet, ce n'est pas la première fois que je rencontre cette ellipse possible : [que / de ce que](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26199)

Comment: @LukeSawczak : Non non! Il ne s'agit pas ici d'une banale ellipse. Le trafic est... bien plus sombre que cela... ;-) Réponse augmentée en conséquence.

Comment: @jlliagre : Agreed! Merci!